# Purging unwanted kernel images in an OpenVZ container

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, openvz

I am aware that similar questions have been asked countless times, but I have not been able so far to find an appropriate match for my case.

I am running a 32-bit, 14.04 server within an OpenVZ container, which provides this kernel:

```
$ uname -r
2.6.32-042stab116.2
```

Not sure how/why it started, but `apt` has been repeatedly trying (and failing) to upgrade to the 3.13 series, ending up like this:

```
$ dpkg -l |grep linux
ii  libselinux1:i386                     2.2.2-1ubuntu0.1                     i386         SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  linux-firmware                       1.127.22                             all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-100             3.13.0-100.147                       all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic     3.13.0-100.147                       i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-101             3.13.0-101.148                       all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-101-generic     3.13.0-101.148                       i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-91              3.13.0-91.138                        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-91-generic      3.13.0-91.138                        i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-92              3.13.0-92.139                        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-92-generic      3.13.0-92.139                        i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-93              3.13.0-93.140                        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic      3.13.0-93.140                        i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-96              3.13.0-96.143                        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-96-generic      3.13.0-96.143                        i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic        3.13.0-92.139                        i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic        3.13.0-93.140                        i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic        3.13.0-96.143                        i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic 3.13.0-100.147                       i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic 3.13.0-101.148                       i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic  3.13.0-92.139                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic  3.13.0-93.140                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-96-generic  3.13.0-96.143                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-libc-dev:i386                  3.13.0-101.148                       i386         Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  syslinux                             3:4.05+dfsg-6+deb8u1                 i386         collection of boot loaders
ii  syslinux-common                      3:4.05+dfsg-6+deb8u1                 all          collection of boot loaders (common files)
ii  util-linux                           2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7                 i386         Miscellaneous system utilities
```

My understanding is that the kernel is entirely under the OpenVZ host's responsibility, and [I have been advised to simply get rid of all these images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853877/ubuntu-14-04-in-an-openvz-container-apt-trying-to-upgrade-the-kernel), which are ignored by the system anyway. However, all my attempts to completely remove the packages have failed with various error messages.

[This is what happened when I tried to explicitly purge all unwanted linux* packages](https://gist.github.com/giuseb/42d45897599e0a3bd454b075dbe5005d).

[Using aptitude instead of apt-get](https://gist.github.com/giuseb/dcc38ab95c52e53b4fd80280809b8649) got rid of a a few packages and changed the status of all remaining images to `pH`, but did not resolve the problem:

```
$ dpkg -l |grep linux
ii  libselinux1:i386                     2.2.2-1ubuntu0.1                     i386         SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  linux-firmware                       1.127.22                             all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-100             3.13.0-100.147                       all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic     3.13.0-100.147                       i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-91              3.13.0-91.138                        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-91-generic      3.13.0-91.138                        i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-92              3.13.0-92.139                        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-92-generic      3.13.0-92.139                        i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-93              3.13.0-93.140                        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-93-generic      3.13.0-93.140                        i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-96              3.13.0-96.143                        all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-96-generic      3.13.0-96.143                        i386         Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
pH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic 3.13.0-100.147                       i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
pH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic 3.13.0-101.148                       i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
pH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic  3.13.0-92.139                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
pH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic  3.13.0-93.140                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
pH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-96-generic  3.13.0-96.143                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-libc-dev:i386                  3.13.0-101.148                       i386         Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  syslinux                             3:4.05+dfsg-6+deb8u1                 i386         collection of boot loaders
ii  syslinux-common                      3:4.05+dfsg-6+deb8u1                 all          collection of boot loaders (common files)
ii  util-linux                           2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7                 i386         Miscellaneous system utilities
```

I ran aptitude again on the above list of 3.13 packages, and this time all headers were gone, but the "extra" images are still there.

```
$ dpkg -l |grep linux
pH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic 3.13.0-100.147                       i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
pH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic 3.13.0-101.148                       i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
pH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic  3.13.0-92.139                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
pH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic  3.13.0-93.140                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
pH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-96-generic  3.13.0-96.143                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
[...]
```

I gave it **yet another go**, [and this is the output](https://gist.github.com/giuseb/db1a9d6e170ec917f0a39b0918a7569e). It looks as though in order to purge these extra images (with obvious unmet dependencies, since the corresponding images are gone) some files required by `aptitude` are missing:

```
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-100-generic: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please provide the exact commands you are running, and the output you obtain.

Comment: @fkraiem, I have gone through several steps, please see my edits, and thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I just noticed that in your first `dpkg -l` command, for some versions you have the `linux-image-extra` packages installed but not the corresponding `linux-image` ones. That's not a good thing, those two packages should always go together. And now you have this for all versions, which is why you can't uninstall the `linux-image-extra` packages. You should reinstall the `linux-image` packages, and then be sure to always remove `linux-image` and `linux-image-extra` together.

Comment: A simple `apt-get -f install` may also help to install the missing `linux-image` packages, bringing you back to a stable state where you can then uninstall everything.

Comment: @fkraiem, yes, having extras without the matching images is clearly problematic, but I have only executed commands via `apt-get` or `aptitude`. I would not dare manually delete stuff. Now, do you mean `apt-get -f install` followed by the list of `*image*` and `*image-extra*` for all the versions? (92, 93, 96, 100, 101)

Comment: No, `apt-get -f install` should be run by itself.

Comment: Given the state of things, `apt-get -f install` by itself will try to REMOVE/PURGE the image-extras, again resulting in errors.

Comment: @fkraiem, hoping it's proper etiquette, I have reformulated my question in a more focused way here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/855755/force-removal-of-unwanted-linux-image-extra-packages

Comment: Sorry, I had been busy. Proper etiquette would probably have been to edit this question, which would also have 'bumped' it to the top.

Comment: @Giuseppe, if the solution in [your other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855755/force-removal-of-unwanted-linux-image-extra-packages) worked, it covers this issue too , we may close this one a duplicate.