# Force removal of unwanted linux-image-extra* packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, kernel, dpkg, openvz

To make a [long story](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854162/purging-unwanted-kernel-images-in-an-openvz-container) short, I am stuck with a handful of unwanted, half-configured image packages that I am trying to get rid of:

```
$ dpkg -l |grep linux-im
iF  linux-image-3.13.0-100-generic       3.13.0-100.147 i386 Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-3.13.0-101-generic       3.13.0-101.148 i386 Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic        3.13.0-92.139  i386 Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic        3.13.0-93.140  i386 Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic        3.13.0-96.143  i386 Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic 3.13.0-100.147 i386 Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic 3.13.0-101.148 i386 Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic  3.13.0-92.139  i386 Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic  3.13.0-93.140  i386 Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iH  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-96-generic  3.13.0-96.143  i386 Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
```

These images are in fact useless, because my 32-bit 14.04 system lives in an OpenVZ container, which is solely responsible for the kernel. As you can see, a much older one:

```
$ uname -r
2.6.32-042stab116.2
```

Thus, unlike most similar questions focusing on how to remove *old* kernel images after routine upgrades, what I am trying to do here is to **COMPLETELY PURGE ALL THESE 3.13 PACKAGES**, which should not be there in the first place.

---

*Here's a summary of my attempts so far.*

Trying to remove/purge the packages the usual ways (`apt-get`, `apt`, `aptitude`, it doesn't matter) does not seem to work, due to an apparent vicious circle.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-100-generic linux-image-3.13.0-101-generic linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-96-generic
```

As you can see from the [output](https://gist.github.com/giuseb/c61778d9f0af8765d21184965981b520), nothing gets actually removed. On the other hand, `aptitude` manages to get a little further:

```
sudo aptitude purge linux-image-3.13.0-100-generic linux-image-3.13.0-101-generic linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic linux-image-3.13.0-93-generic linux-image-3.13.0-96-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-96-generic
```

At the end of [this process](https://gist.github.com/giuseb/d12695a743696df1a8b8a20bfdf0322a), the `*image-3.13*`s are gone, together with matching files and folders normally found in `/boot` and in `/lib/modules`, but the `image-extra`s are still reported as half-installed (even though they appear to contain no files, as verified by `dpkg -L`...)

Furthermore, dependencies are now broken, as repeating the purge at this stage causes apt to complain about missing files/folders in  `/boot` and in `/lib/modules`. I tried to place dummy files at the expected locations, as [suggested here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264110), but in the end I run into the original errors. The following, I believe, is the crucial excerpt:

```
[...]
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic (3.13.0-101.148) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-101-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-101-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-101-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-101-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-101-generic (--purge):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
[...]
```

After trying, unsuccessfully, a [supposedly nuclear option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525088/how-to-delete-broken-packages-in-ubuntu):

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package_name
```

I ran out of ideas.

Comment: I've been digging under the hood a bit, and I have a hunch that the error stems from `dpgk` running the scripts in `/etc/kernel/postrm.d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that:

- the `linux-image-3.13.0-XXX-generic` were successfully purged
- the `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-XXX-generic` are still reported as half-installed
- no currently installed packages depend on these `image-extra`s
- none of these images should be there in the first place (since the 2.6 kernel is provided by the host OpenVZ container)
- none of the traditional attempts succeed in cleaning the system

Then a possible approach is to forcefully purge those dangling entries from the `dpkg` database, as [suggested here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264110).

**PLEASE NOTE: this is a hackish, low-level, potentially dangerous operation.**

- look for any files belonging to the package you want to remove (try `$ dpkg -L linux-image-extra-3.13.0-XXX-generic`) and delete them
- open the file `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, locate and delete the block(s) of text describing the package(s) you want dpkg to forget about
- be extra careful about preserving blank lines between package descriptors, spaces at the beginning of lines, etc. They say the apt database is unforgiving of typos.
- after saving the status file, `dpkg` as well as all `apt`-related programs should be back to normal

Answer (score 1):

I use the following in a bash script to nuke everything but the active kernel:

```
dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e "$(uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-")" | grep -e "[0-9]" | grep -E "(image|headers)" | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

It is quite close to what you've invoked but perhaps `dpkg` is the necessary difference.

The full set of scripts are here if interested:
https://github.com/mtompkins/linux-kernel-utilities

Comment: as far as I can tell, this line simply invokes `apt-get purge` on all applicable packages. I have already attempted that numerous times, to no avail.

Comment: That is indeed all it does but I was unsure if you were properly passing the package names in some sense and was hopeful the `dpkg` invocation might handle it. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `ls /boot` should show some `vmlinuz-X.XX.XX` files. Do `apt-get purge linux-image-X.XX.XX-generic` for each one, but **DO NOT REMOVE** the kernel you are running. You can check which one with `uname -r`.

Comment: @Zanna fixed question.

Comment: cool, I suggest leaving one spare kernel too

Comment: @MarkYisri, the `/boot` folder shows NO entries at all. As I wrote, Ubuntu is running inside an OpenVZ container, and the kernel (see the Q) belongs to the host, I have no control over it. Also, failing to `apt-get purge` these irrelevant packages is the essence of the problem is described.